# Returning variable from jquery on select function to another jquery on click fucntion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to the value of `paramValue` from `.change` event function into `var searchValue` to be displayed together at `.click` event. `console.log(paramDD)` gives me "undefined".

```
       $( '#userSearchParam' ).change(function paramDropDown(){
            var paramValue = $(this).val();
            console.log(paramValue);
            return paramValue;
        });

        var paramDD = paramDropDown();
        console.log(paramDD);

        $('#userSearchBtn').click(function () {

            var textBoxValue = $('#userSearchBox').val();
            console.log(textBoxValue);
            var searchValue = textBoxValue + paramDD;
            console.log(searchValue);
        });
```

Comment: If you put this in a jsfiddle I can play with it a bit

Comment: Why not just on click, get the value from the select box? `$( '#userSearchParam' ).val()`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sfoy961r/ here you go

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function paramDropDown(){
    var paramValue = $('#userSearchParam').val();
    console.log(paramValue);
    return paramValue;
}

$( '#userSearchParam' ).change(paramDropDown);

var paramDD = paramDropDown();
console.log(paramDD);
```

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish though. If you can let us know your use case maybe we can recommend a solution.

Comment: There is a dropdown with some options and a textbox  I want to get the value of both to be sent as a part of API get call. dropdown is the paramerter and text box is the search text for the selected parameter.